# How to send a meeting request by email from SharePoint 2010 to an iPhone

Tags: iphone, email, sharepoint-2010, exchange-server

As part of a Windows Workflow hosted on SharePoint we want to send a meeting request to non-active directory users, some of whom will most likely use an iPhone. We are currently using WebDav to talk to Exchange which sends out the email containing the request. The mail is successfully received as a calendar item in Gmail, Hotmail, Windows Live & Outlook, but on the iPhone the email appears to contain an `.ics` file (which can't be opened) and with no body.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the problem is with the iPhone not supporting the .ics attachment. It sounds as if everything else is in line.

Here's a discussion on the [Apple Support forums - ".ics files - outlook meeting.ics attachment won't open"](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1653278&start=45&tstart=0).

It appears that the iPhone still doesn't support .ics attachments.